# Количество методов в библиотеке(android)

Tags: android, методы, methodscount

Количество методов в библиотеке(android), есть сайт methodscount, отдаю библиотеку он возвращает информации сколько методов, Total count - это общее количество методов? 
Methods count это что? 
Dependencies methods count это что?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже что Total count = Methods count + Dependencies methods. Последние, видимо, методы внутри подключённых к библиотеке друших библиотек

Comment: в проекте  16653 методов будет?

Comment: Получается, что при подключении этой либы кол-во методов в проекте увеличится на `Total count`. Если ещё какие-то либы подключать в которых будут дублировать подзависимости, то добавлять надо будет уже не совсем `TotalCount` новой либы